# Geo Django GDAL Exception OGR Failure

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango, osgeo

I'm using geo django and running on windows. I do have GDAL and OSGEOS configured in the settings.

**Here is my settings.py code for gdal.**

```
   import os
    if os.name == 'nt':
        import platform
        OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
        if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
            OSGEO4W += "64"
        assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
        os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
        os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
        os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
        os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
```

**I have a model that has a pointfield.
model:**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True)
```

**Whenever I try to create an event and set the pointfield value, I get this error:**

```
GDAL_ERROR 6: b'Unable to load PROJ.4 library (proj.dll), creation of\nOGRCoordin
ateTransformation failed.'
Error transforming geometry from srid '4326' to srid '3857' (OGR failure.)
```

This problem seems to be a windows only issue. When I run this application on ubuntu on my virtualbox, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: how did you install gdal?

Comment: I think you didn't install gdal properly.

Comment: I've also `django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: OGR failure.` Did you fix it? I've install GDAL through the https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to settings file

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\epsg_csv" <- (path to gcs.csv file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not been able to resolve this issue for windows. What I did to bypass this issue was install ubuntu on windows using oracle virtualbox.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads